# Cannot convert project... Premature end of file error in Intellij IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA as an IDE for running Java programs. Dues to power fluctuation computer got restarted. Now when I launch the IDE after reboot i am getting the error `Cannot convert project: /home/aniket/IdeaProjects/JavaDemoCodes/.idea/workspace.xml: Error on line -1: Premature end of file.`

Has anyone encountered this situation before? What can I do to view my project back again?

Comment: What does `/home/aniket/IdeaProjects/JavaDemoCodes/.idea/workspace.xml` look like?

Comment: workspace.xml file might be broken already. So you may wanna delete .idea folder and create a project from existing source.

Comment: `.idea/workspace.xml` can be deleted. Does it help?

Comment: @elbek your method kind of worked.

Comment: @CrazyCoder no such file existed. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @lefloh again the same no such file existed. Thanks though!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also had this after a power failure, I simply deleted the workspace.xml file from the projects .idea folder, restarted IntelliJ and it seemed to be OK apart from loosing which files were open.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: +1 Same thing happened to me after a power failure. Deleting workspace.xml solved the problem, but I lost some project configuration such as the font used.

Comment: Ditto... I'm now quite curious what happens during power failure that causes this.

Comment: computers are complicated things.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error when my laptop bluescreened.  I solved it by:

- Exit IntelliJ IDEA
- Rename .idea folder
- Start IntelliJ IDEA
- Create new project from existing sources
- Exit IntelliJ IDEA
- Copy all files from old .idea folder to newly created one.
- Restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I would only change: 'copy all' to 'copy all except workspace.xml'

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem. Hers is the solution. First of all I had two Intellij IDEA projects open in  two separate windows.

One was the project which had corresponding subversion repository. This was a `file-based format project`. Files that define a project are `.iws, .ipr and .iml`. .iws is the one corresponding to the workspace configuration. I just reverted back this file with `svn revert project.iws` and I could launch my project again.

But the problem in second project `JavaDemoCodes` still persisted as it was custom project I created and it looks by default we get a directory-based format project instead of `file-based format project`. This has all its configurations in /home/aniket/.IdeaIC12 directory. As many of you suggested i searched for workspace.xml here but could not find it. I tried  `find . -name *.xml` but i still could not find it(Also as the error suggests there is no file `/home/aniket/IdeaProjects/JavaDemoCodes/.idea/workspace.xml` ).Finally I did import project from my first project(the one with svn repo) it detected my `JavaDemoCodes` project as Intellij IDEA project and let me open it in new window.

Not sure if this is the perfect answer but it solved my problem and yes as someone suggested I deleted .iws file from my 1st svn repo based project and tried to restart but was of no help. New .iws file was created but it still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same problem.  It happens to me when I have IntelliJ open and for whatever reason (usually problems with having multiple VPN connections open), my computer freezes and I have to do a forced re-boot.

My solution is to use Windows 7 restore.  I'll go to the folder it is complaining about, right click on it, and do a restore.  If I'm lucky, I have a restore point only a few days old.

For me, rebuilding my configuration on several projects from scratch is too time consuming.  Using a restore point from a few days or even a week makes more sense.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just by creating a new project, then starting it and then reopening the old project..